# 3D object / Augmented Reality Libraries for iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, 3d, augmented-reality

I want to create an augmented reality application for the iPhone.

To be more specific, I want to create a 3D object of certain dimensions that will be superimposed on the camera's input so that the user can "move around" the object.

Are there any libraries for creating (or at least trying to create..) such objects/applications for the iphone?

Comment: Something like [ARToolkit](http://www.hitl.washington.edu/artoolkit/documentation/usersetup.htm#comp_macos) you mean? I personally don't know about objective-c or xcode, so I kept it a comment.

Comment: Thanks for your input Bart, ARToolkit looks like it can do the job and it works with Mac OS xCode Tools :) If anyone has any other suggestions feel free to let me know!

Comment: there are not as much open source libraries of Augmented realty in iOS, I searched a lot of and could not find a single open source MIT license library other than ARToolkit which is made for ios6 only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the Mobile SDK from metaio: http://www.metaio.com/sdk/

It will be easier to use than ARToolKit, as it abstracts the AR functionality on a higher level, e.g. it has an integrated renderer that lets you load OBJ and MD2 models.

Comment: the link is fixed now.

Comment: $4500 for a "basic" licence. Ouch!

Answer (score 1):

See this version of Augmented Reality Toolkit 
https://github.com/a1phanumeric/iPhone-AR-Toolkit